# How does a Java if statement work when it has an assignment and an equality check OR - d together?

Tags: java

Why does this if statement, with an assignment and equality check, evaluate to false?

```
public static void test() {

    boolean test1 = true; 
    if (test1 = false || test1 == false) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }       
}
```

Why is this printing `No`?

Comment: that is why you should always use parenthesis in these kind of situations

Comment: The answer you got are not explaining the problem fully or are dead wrong. Please refer to the linked question, which is _exactly_ the same.

Answer (score 14):

Because of [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). It is equivalent to this:

```
boolean test1 = true; 
if (test1 = (false || test1 == false)) {
...
}
```

The part in brackets evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Reign: `test1 = false` both sets the value *and* has a result, `false`. The result of assignment is the value assigned.

Answer (score -1):

you are assigning value to var in if statement, but not using it. If you want to assign in if statement and use, you can do this:

```
boolean test1;
if ((test1 = false) == true) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Well, sure. But then if you're going to change things, you could just write `boolean test1 = false; System.out.println("No");`, and there'd be no confusion.

Comment: yes sorry, i will edit it :P thx

Answer (score -1):

You have the following operators in your `if` statement, which are priorized like this: *equality* > *logical OR* > *assignment*

The if is then reducing like this:

```
(test1 = false || test1 == false) //substituing test1 with its value

(test1 = false || true == false) //evaluating equality

(test1 = false || false) //evaluating logical OR

(test1 = false) //evaluating assignment

(test1) //substituing test1 with its value

(false) //evaluating primitive value, going to else block
```

Hence printing *No*.

Comment: No. [Java evaluates left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). The assignment is done before equality.

Comment: @AndyTurner If the assignment is evaluated first, it should have printed *Yes*, right ?

Comment: @AndyTurner `((test1 = false) || test1 == false)` would have printed *Yes*.

Comment: `((test1 = false) || test1 == false)` is a different expression.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know, but it was to emphasize that without parenthesis the assignment can't be evaluated first, otherwise the OP's code would have printed *Yes*.

Comment: What I meant to say was *equality is not evaluated first*. The first operand of the `||` is evaluated first, is found to be false, and then the equality check is performed.

Comment: @AndyTurner If I follow your reasoning it should be: `(test1 = false || test1 == false)` => `(false || test1 == false)` => `(false || false == false)` => `(false || true)` => `(true)` ?

Comment: No. It should be `(test1 = false || test1 == false) => (test1 = test1 == false) => (test1 = false) => (false)`, because that's how the operator precedence works.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't get it. In your second step, test1's value should be `false` because the assignment has been performed ?

Answer (score -2):

The result of this code will print "no" as you are assigning the test1 as false
       test1 = false
the if statement then evaluates to false because you then you evaluate the            test1 == false
and else block executes

this might be what you are looking for :

```
   if ((test1 == false) || (test1 == false)) //this line if the first answer is true it returns true without checking the seconded statement.  
     // if (test1 == false) would be the, same elauates as true 
     {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

look in the shortcircuit or operator this might help you better grasp the issue